# showDelay for tooltip in sencha is being showed at wrong place. once mouse goes out from the target item

Tags: javascript, extjs

In bar/column chart, when we want to show a tooltip after some delay and take the mouse out from target element, it is being shown at current mouse position instead it should be shown on target element where mouse was first entered or last position from which mouseout event called.

sencha version : 5.0.0.970.

```
    Ext.application({
        name: 'PanelHeaderItems',

        launch: function() {

            var graphStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
                fields: ['kg', 'ha'],
                data: [{
                    "kg": "0.23",
                    "ha": "2"
                }, {
                    "kg": "0.4",
                    "ha": "5"
                }, {
                    "kg": "0.6",
                    "ha": "7"
                }, {
                    "kg": "0.8",
                    "ha": "9"
                }, {
                    "kg": "0.95",
                    "ha": "13"
                }]
            });

            wizardStep3Chart = new Ext.chart.CartesianChart({
                width: 400,
                height: 300,
                animation: true,
                store: graphStore,
                legend: {
                    position: 'right'
                },
                axes: [{
                    type: 'numeric',
                    position: 'left',
                    grid: true,
                    fields: ['ha'],
                    renderer: function(v) {
                        return v;
                    }
                }, {
                    type: 'numeric',
                    position: 'bottom',
                    grid: true,
                    adjustByMajorUnit: false,
                    fields: ['kg'],
                    label: {
                        rotate: {
                            degrees: -45
                        }
                    }
                }],
                series: [{
                    type: 'bar',
                    axis: 'left',
                    xField: 'kg',
                    yField: 'ha',
                    style: {
                        opacity: 0.80
                    },
                    highlight: {
                        fillStyle: '#125489',
                        lineWidth: 2,
                        strokeStyle: '#fff'
                    },
                    tooltip: {
                        trackMouse: true,
                        showDelay: 2000,
                        style: 'background: #fff',
                        renderer: function(storeItem, item) {
                            this.setHtml(storeItem.get('ha') + ': ' + storeItem.get('kg'));
                        }
                    }
                }],
                renderTo: Ext.getBody()
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: provide some code to work with

Comment: It's always great to create JsFiddle, easier for other to see the problem, investigate, provide solution

Comment: I created a Fidller for you. Can you please explain bit more. https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1dqi

Comment: thanks UDID, but above fiddle doesnt work for mentioned version 5.0.0.97